# What means wrapper is null in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, mootools, firebug, wrapper

I have an error in this page:

http://colombianadederecho.org

And with Firebug I obtain this, but I don't understand what this means or how to resolve.

```
wrapper is null
(?)()2 (línea 1)
element = "#menu ul"
items = "#menu li a"
options = Object { widthSliderPx=125, widthSliderOpenPx=185}
Class()mootools.js.php (línea 16)
start()
```

Thanks

Comment: again why the downvote???? come on.. this is a valid question.. lets not down vote people for asking things that they do not fully understand.. is that not the point of the site?

Comment: Why someone downvote the question and didn't leave any comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Chrome console, I see this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of null
```

Which means that some piece of JavaScript is trying to do something like this:

```
var foo = null;
foo.addEvent(...);
```

Perhaps it's doing a `document.getElementById()` and then (trying to) add an event listener, but no such element with the specified ID was found.

---

My Chrome console reports a few possible line numbers:

[image]

Here's line 345 of `template.js.php`:

```
var menuFx = new SliderMenu('#menu ul', '#menu li a', { widthSliderPx: YtSettings.widthSliderPx, widthSliderOpenPx: YtSettings.widthSliderOpenPx });
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. It appears that is a bad call of a mootools function or something like that. Is there a way to obtain more info about where is this bug generated?

Comment: Thanks Matt, your answer give me a place where to begin the search. That file template.js.php includes other files and in the console all merged in one.

Comment: Finally I commented a line of code not necessary in an included file and now works! Matt how do you attach images to your answer? It is a special privilege or everybody can do that?

Comment: [You just need 10 rep.](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) `Ctrl-G` while editing, or click the editor icon that looks like a Polaroid.

Comment: Thanks. Your help was very useful. Since is not common to see images I supposed it was something special.

Answer (score 1):

Like Matt, I also see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of null
```

From what I can tell, it's coming from this line of code in template.js.php:

```
var menuFx = new SliderMenu('#menu ul', '#menu li a', { widthSliderPx: YtSettings.widthSliderPx, widthSliderOpenPx: YtSettings.widthSliderOpenPx });
```

I can't step into the compressed code to track through it, but one guess is that it's because you don't have "#menu ul" in your code which results in a null somewhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 for your answer.